# I can't write in Windows partition, but I've done it before

Tags: partitioning, permissions

Before, I could save images downloaded from the web in the Windows partition. Even I could transfer files and all that. But today, I can't do it anymore.

Some days ago, I was trying to resize Ubuntu and Windows partition. I downloaded GParted, and I tried to shrink the Windows partition, then increase the Ubuntu partition, but as I couldn't do that, I never applied the Windows' shrinking.

I mentioned this because I think it caused this problem. When I tried to transfer some file or save an image from the web as I did before, there appears a message which says the partition has no writing permission, that is read-only, or something like that.

Could someone help me? If you need more specific info, ask me please.

Comment: I already solved it. I looked up on the web, and this worked.
http://www.howtoforge.com/ntfs_3g_ubuntu_feisty
Unfortunatelly, I don't do it methodologically. First I went to Synaptic and searched ntfs, such as indicated in the link. But at the same time, I was uninstalling GParted. It seems GParted install others things with it, wich affects the default writing permissions on ntfs. So I dont know wot solvd the prob. After that, I tryed to "write" on the Windows partition and I get the same message. Then I reboot hoping it was all needed, and it was so. I can write on Windows partition again.

Comment: Hmmm, I have several grammar errors, but I think it can be understand.

Comment: It is better if you answer your own question and accept that answer. That way, it will be visible to others that the question is answered, making it more useful.

Comment: I tryed that, but I can do it until ~8 hours later... I will as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved it. I looked up on the web, and this worked. http://howtoforge.com/ntfs_3g_ubuntu_feisty 
Unfortunatelly, I don't do it methodologically. First I went to Synaptic and searched ntfs, such as indicated in the link. But at the same time, I was uninstalling GParted. It seems GParted installs others things with it, wich affects the default writing permissions on ntfs. So I don't know exactly what solved the problem. After that, I tryed to "write" on the Windows partition and I get the same message. Then I reboot hoping it was all needed, and it was so. I can write on Windows partition again.

Comment: I can set my own answer as accepted until tomorrow. I will do it as soon as I can.